# Loopback ng-sdk model not updating when using $q.resolve

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

Im using Loopback Angular SDK, and, when im updating a model, if i use $q.resolve, the model doesnt update.

Example:

```
bpmService.createDocument(newDocument)
  .then(function (nd) {
     Oc.prototype$updateAttributes({originalOc.id, documentId: nd.document.id}).$promise
       .then(function(res){                 
            deferred.resolve(res);                 
        });
     });
```

The weird issue is, when i comment the line //deferred.resolve(res); the model updates!!!

Im missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after several attemps i make my changes work.

First, create a separate function to handle the update:

```
this.saveUpdatedOc = function(originalOc){
     return Oc.prototype$updateAttributes({id: originalOc.id, documentId: originalOc.newDocumentId}).$promise
});};
```

Then, call them in order from the controller

```
ocService.doTransition(transitionObject)
            .then(function (updatedDocument) {
                data.oc.newDocumentId = _.clone(data.oc.documentId);
                ocService.saveUpdatedOc(data.oc)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        //END OF FUNCTION
                    });
            });
```

And now is working!!! So, it seems the best way is use separate functions in the service to handle calls. If anyone has a better explanation about this, i will be very happy to read it.